# How to convert cURL to retrofit correct form?

Tags: java, android, url, curl, retrofit2

Sorry for my English. I want use this [service](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/alchemy-language/api/v1/?curl#language). For determine the language of the text.

Request(Curl):

```
curl -X POST -d "outputMode=json" --data-urlencode text@ibm.txt -d "url=http://www.ibm.com/us-en/" "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/calls/text/TextGetLanguage?apikey=%API_KEY%"
```

I use Retrofit for request.

```
public interface LanguageDetectionApi {
    public static final String ROOT_URL = "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/calls/";

    @POST("/text/TextGetLanguage")
    Call<List<PostModel>> getData(@Query("apikey") String apikey, @Query("text") String text);
}
```

Create retrofit object:

```
public class App extends Application {

    private static LanguageDetectionApi _languageDetectionApi;
    private Retrofit _retrofit;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        _retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(_languageDetectionApi.ROOT_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        _languageDetectionApi = _retrofit.create(LanguageDetectionApi.class);
    }


    public static LanguageDetectionApi getLanguageDetectionApi() {
        return _languageDetectionApi;
    }
}
```

And send request:

```
App app = new App();
        app.onCreate();

        app.getLanguageDetectionApi().getData("4978e60252ae102dfe1341146bb8cc3ec4bbbd78", textForRecognition).enqueue(new Callback<List<PostModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<PostModel>> call, Response<List<PostModel>> response) {
                List<PostModel> posts = new ArrayList<>();
                posts.addAll(response.body());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<PostModel>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "An error occurred during networking", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

PostModel i generated in site http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/.

Questions:
No response comes to me, although apikey are exactly valid.
How to specify in the interface parametr "outputMode=json"?
And I translated correctly cURL to LanguageDetectionApi?
It seems to me that the whole mistake in the class LanguageDetectionApi. Can you help deal with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

change url code like below:

```
public interface LanguageDetectionApi {
    public static final String ROOT_URL = "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net";

    @POST("/calls/text/TextGetLanguage")
    Call<List<PostModel>> getData(@Query("apikey") String apikey, @Query("text") String text);
}
```

base url should be ony host name.